# How to change org citation appearance as viewed in org-mode (i.e. not after exporting)

Tags: org-mode, org-ref

If I insert a citation into a `.org` file, (via `helm-bibtex`, `citar` or `C-c C-l`), I get a link in the buffer that looks like

`Cite:&jaynesInformationTheoryStatistical1957`.

I can do `C-c C-l` on the link and change the description to something a bit more readable, like `Jaynes, 1957`, or longer like `Jaynes, Information Theory and Statistical Mechanics II`.

Is there a way to make the link description automatically take a tidier format, or look like any of the commonly used citation styles, within the `.org` buffer itself? (I.e. I'm not concerned about what the citation looks like once the `.org` buffer is exported to `.pdf` document or a `.tex` file).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like an org-ref link. I haven't used this package: https://github.com/alezost/org-ref-prettify.el, but it claims to do something similar to what you want.

Some alternatives include writing an interactive function to add the description of your choice, or add an :activate-func to the citation links that puts an overlay on them.

Comment: This was precisely what I was looking for, thanks! Thanks as well for all your work on `org-ref`; I started using it when I had nearly zero Emacs knowledge but it seems to have built itself into my workflow. Unfortunately that comes with a lot of technical debt but maybe one day I'll clean it up!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about `helm-bibtex` but I use `reftex` and see pretty links in my Org buffer, but proper exported `\textcite{...}`, with this code. If I want it to look pretty I use `T` or `P`, other wise `t` or `p`.

```
(define-key global-map (kbd "C-c r") 'reftex-citation)
(setq reftex-cite-format
      '((?
 . "citep:%l")
    (?t . "citet:%l")   ; Author (YYY)
    (?T . "[[citet:%l][%A (%y)]]")   ; Author (YYY)
    (?p . "citep:%l") ; (Author, YYYY)
    (?P . "[[citep:%l][(%A, %y)]]") ; (Author, YYYY)
    (?n . "nocite:%l") ; (Author, YYYY) but NO EXPORT
    (?a . ",%l")  ;; add just a link to existing cite
    ))
```

Comment: Thanks! I think I can see what this is doing, and somewhere in the bowels of my config I have `reftex`, `reftex-citation` and `org-reftex-citation`. Unfortunately the formatting doesn't quite work, e.g. `T` gives me `[[citet:jaynesInformationTheoryStatistical1957a][Jaynes ()]]`, and similarly for `P` -- there is some mashing of the link and the link description. I think I can debug this if I can find a spare hour.

Comment: `C-c t runs the command org-toggle-link-display (found in
org-mode-map)`

Comment: What is the BibTex entry for Jaynes 1957? Mine would be `year = 1957,`. Is yours `Year` or something else??

Comment: I have my entry as `date = {1957-05-15},`. There are two Jaynes papers from 1957 with the same title, so the second one is cited as `1957a`.

Comment: So this may be BibLaTeX vs BiBTeX. No YEAR, no reftex completion of year. Maybe change %y to something that pulls the string from the date field?

Comment: Ah I should have been more clear, when I said `[[citet:jaynesInformationTheoryStatistical1957a][Jaynes ()]]`, I mean literally that everything in that code block appears as the link instead of just `Jaynes ()` (the date/year part is a separate issue).